# How to use a set of jar files in classpath in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, build-automation

How to make this possible ?

I had a set of jar files which are to be included to CLASSPATH variable.

I don't want to give the command `SET CLASSPATH=xxx.jar;xx.jar;..` as part of the build step.

I dont' want to **manually** set the Environment variable CLASSPATH as part of system properties.

I tried by copying a set of jar files into `Jenkins_HOME/war/WEB-INF/lib` and had started the Jenkins server. But couldn't make it possible... Any Solution ?

Comment: What are the JAR files? Why do you want them on Jenkins' classpath?

Comment: @wulfgar.pro I need jar files which are required for all the jobs.. Some of them are junit.jar, selenium.jar

Comment: How have you installed Jenkins? Using the war, or a native binary? If the war, what container are you deploying to?

Comment: @wulfgar.pro I am directly running the war file as follows .. java -jar jenkins.war

Comment: Have you tried using the -cp switch when invoking the jvm?

Comment: That's what i say. I don't want to use the -CP option / SET CLASSPATH / export CLASSPATH in the command.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19981/discussion-between-harsha-and-wulfgar-pro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set CLASSPATH environment as follows and any jar file updated it particular directory

SET CLASSPATH=`<your_lib_directory>\*`

This will pick up all the updated JAR files

Answer (score 0):

You can try by additional class-path elements maven. you can see the details in below link
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <additionalClasspathElements>
        <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/additional/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
        <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/additional/jar</additionalClasspathElement>
        <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/csv/jar1, path/to/csv/jar2</additionalClasspathElement>
      </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are making things harder on yourself than needs be. Why don't you want to set the classpath as  a pre-build step? Perhaps because the artifacts change regularly?

My suggestion is that you look into building with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and convert your Jenkins job to a Maven job - then you can handle your extra dependencies in the POM and not in Jenkins - which may be a little more elegant.

For example, your JUnit and Selenium dependencies could be included as

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ... etc
```

(the `<scope>` being important to keep them out of your final artifact) and in the Jenkins job configuration, "Goals and options" could be `test package`.

Hope that helps.

Cheers,

Comment: I couldn't use maven as it doesn't have internet access & resources are confined to local network i.e. Intranet

Comment: Maven can run offline and/or you can have your JARs in a `localrepository/...` in your project.

Comment: My thought is that, coming future, even if updated the jar file versions, I will just copy the latest jar file into a specific location & restart jenkins, so that the classpath is updated automatically...

Comment: this does not answer the question