# PMD + jenkins [linux] - class net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD not found

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, pmd

I need to run PMD on my Jenkins server [LINUX]. 
Everything works fine on my Windows machine with sh.exe but when I am trying to run it on Jenkins I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD

I know it means that it cannot find the main class but the exact same thing works on my local env. 
 
Both machines have `java version "1.7.0_111"` and `pmd-bin-5.5.2`. 
What is wrong with this? Please help.

Thank You.

Comment: Does anyone knows ?

Comment: Is it on your classpath? I think you can use `CLASSPATH` variable for that in your build [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508958/how-to-use-a-set-of-jar-files-in-classpath-in-jenkins). Not very familiar with java. What is your setup?